# Есть Активити, в котором очень много различных эллементов, они долго подгружаются,  что делать?

Tags: android, java

Есть Активити, в котором очень много различных эллементов, при его открытии слишком долго подгружается, секунды 3-4, а иногда приложение и вовсе закрывается, что делать?

Comment: Сферический абстрактный вопрос в вакууме.Мы не знаем ни о структуре вашего слоя, ни о вложенности элементов и т.п.

Так что, основываясь на ваших данных, мы можем дать только один совет: оптимизируйте.

Comment: может быть Вы пытаетесь сделать listview, только ручками? или в onCreate подгружаете данные с медленного ресурса (с карты памяти, с интернета).

Comment: Нет, в моем активити есть скроллвью, в котором очень много линерлэйаутов, на одном телефоне этот активити открывается, а на другом приложение крашится. И я не думаю ,что это зависит от телефона.

Comment: > скроллвью, в котором очень много линерлэйаутов

Очень похоже на попытку изобрести свой `ListView`, о чём я вам и говорил в [вашем предыдущем вопросе][1].

  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/351368/java-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: Да знаю, но я никогда до этого не работал с ЛистВью и поэтому не знаю как его кастомизировать, чтобы получить такие блоки какие мне надо. Может как-то можно подгрузить это Активити при запуске приложения, а при его вызове оно уже будет подгружено и откроется?

Comment: > но я никогда до этого не работал с ЛистВью

Ну так самое время начать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Лучше подставлять лэйауты по очереди не в onCreate, а в onStart
2. Проверять оставшуюся память. Имеет смысл выставить в манифесте largeHeap="true"
3. Возможно поможет [это](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: Кстати с largeHeap="true" можно получить геморрой. Если приложение интенсивно использует память, то она будет быстро засорятся, а сборщик мусора по большой куче будет долго бежать - в итоге тормоза.

Comment: @danpetruk, огромное спасибо, но я уже решил проблему по другому, разделил активити на страницы, но на будущее буду знать, еще раз спасибо)